# Javascript - Strange Behavior with TypedArray.prototype.set

Tags: javascript, typed-arrays

I was playing around with JavaScript's TypedArrays when I noticed something a bit strange. I figured the implementation of the TypedArray.prototype.set method would simply copy values incrementally. Thus, I tried tricking the system to see this behavior:

```
var ar = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
ar.set(ar.subarray(0,6),2);
```

I perceived that, if it started copying from `ar` at 0, but overwrote values at 2, the subarray would be manipulated, and thus start looping once it reached index 2. Therefore, I would naturally expect an output of `Uint8Array(8) [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]`, but, when inspecting `ar`:

```
> ar
Uint8Array(8) [1,2,1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

So, I figured perhaps it copied backwards?

```
var ar = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
ar.set(ar.subarray(2),0);

> ar
Uint8Array(8) [3,4,5,6,7,8,7,8]
```

Nope. Rather unsettled by this, I then decided to use a Proxy to inspect internal behavior:

```
ar = new Uint8Array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
pxy = new Proxy(ar.subarray(0,6),{
    get: (o,p)=>{console.log("get",o,p,o[p]); return o[p]}
});

> ar.set(pxy,2);
get Uint32Array(6) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] length 6
get Uint32Array(6) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 0 1
get Uint32Array(6) [1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6] 1 2
get Uint32Array(6) [1, 2, 1, 2, 5, 6] 2 1
get Uint32Array(6) [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 6] 3 2
get Uint32Array(6) [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2] 4 1
get Uint32Array(6) [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2] 5 2

> ar
Uint8Array(8) [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]
```

And, alas, as soon as I attempt to observe it, it sneaks away and acts as I first anticipated!

I've run this test in Chrome and Firefox, and both give the same results. I also tested it in MS Edge, and it also seems to give the same results (though at times it would randomly crash the JS runtime - perhaps it was related to the proxy).

Is this a bug or is this specified behavior? When (and/or why) should I expect this behavior? Or should I just altogether evade setting a TypedArray to its own subarray?

Comment: Actually, looking at the specification, your described behavior is well-defined. I'll post an answer later when I have time, but your first example satisfies the assertion in step 1 of [22.2.3.22.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%typedarray%.prototype.set-typedarray-offset) while your example with proxy does not, so it falls back to [22.2.3.22.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%typedarray%.prototype.set-array-offset) which does not compare the soruce and target buffers or internally clone the source array buffer in the case they overlap.

Comment: And for a visual, the Mozilla docs have a helpful example that is pretty similar to your first case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is specified behaviour. You can count on this.

When you `set` a typed array to its own subarray (i.e. when both typed arrays are views on the same buffer), the source area is explicitly *cloned* before being written into the destination. This is so that the `[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]` result is prevented - it is usually unwanted and unexpected.

Using a proxy to inspect the internal behaviour failed you here because using a proxy changed the behaviour. What I said above applies only when you pass another typed array to the `set` method - but a `Proxy` (even with a typed array target) does not count as a typed array. It falls back to normal copying like from any other array-like object, which does work as you initially described.

Comment: Well I guess my potential answer got swiped ;) Have an upvote (I was in a meeting)